# MonoTouch.Dialog: Getting StringElement to have an AccessoryView

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

When a StringElement has A Tapped Action associated with it, how do I get it to display a UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator ?

I can subclass it and roll my own, but I'd rather stick to the MonoTouch.Dialog framework.

```
StringElement s = new StringElement (item.Title);
s.Tapped += delegate { ShowDomainItem (s); };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try StyledStringElement that allows many more settings to be configured than the StringElement.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on what Miguel said:

`new StyledStringElement ("Movie Cast") { Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator }`